# Azure File Store mapping over site-to-site VPN

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Need to map the file store, but our ISP is blocking 445 and there's no reasoning with them.

As a workaround, I've set up a site-to-site VPN, but I can't seem to find an option to assign a virtual IP to the file store. How do I access it from my machine and how do test if the VPN is working fine (it shows it's up, but there's no incoming traffic)?

Answer (score 0):

Azure files is a PaaS service, it is not connected to your virtual network, which is where your VPN terminates. You would need to ensure that traffic to PaaS resources (in this case *.files.core.windows.net) is routed over your VPN connection.

Comment: Bummer! Doesn't seem like a routed IPSec is an option on this gateway device.